# Why is doing a computation inside Select slower than a precomputation?

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation, timing

I am trying to generate primitive Pythogorean triples using Euclid's parametrization. I basically want a list of pairs with ordered pairs $(m,n)$ such that $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

My first approach was

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 list1 = Flatten[Table[{m, n}, {m, 1, 20000, 2}, {n, 2, 20000, 2}], 1];
 list2 = Select[list1, (GCD[#[[1]], #[[2]]] == 1) &];]

(*{223.175, Null}*)
```

in which I first produce a list of pairs where $m$ is always odd and $n$ is always even. Then I use `Select` to select the pairs where both coordinates are coprime. I quit and restarted a local kernel with a simple computation like `2+2` to make sure there are no effects due to caching, garbage cleanup, or something like that. I then timed the whole thing and got 223 seconds.

My second approach was

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 list1 = Flatten[
   Table[{m, n, GCD[m, n]}, {m, 1, 20000, 2}, {n, 2, 20000, 2}], 1];
 list2 = Select[list1, #[[3]] == 1 &];]

(*{161.464, Null}*)
```

in which I compute a third column inside the `Table` which is the GCD of $m$ and $n$. Then I used `Select` to simply pick the lists where the third coordinate is one. Restarting the kernel as before and timing it gives me only 161 seconds, which is almost 40% faster.

**Why is the first method slower?** I don't care about the memory usage. Obviously storing the third column will take more memory.

My thoughts,

- I would expect both of them to take roughly the same amount of time. If anything, I would expect the second approach to be slower. We are flattening an array with more elements.
- They are both vectorized approaches.
- The kernel is doing all of the work (instead of the front-end) in both cases.
- The number of GDC operations is the same in both cases.
- The number of comparisons is the same in both cases.
- In the first case, `Select` is scanning row-by-row, computing the GCD, and comparing it to one.
- In the second case, `Table` is computing the GCD row-by-row and `Select` is only scanning the third column and comparing it to one.

Which of these, if any, is wrong? The only thing I can think of is that in the first approach `Select` is scanning both the first and the second column. In the second approach `Select` is only concerned with the third column *ignoring the first two columns completely*. Is this true?

**What is going on here?** What are the lesson to be learned here, in the context of writing fast MMA code?

Comment: Use `Pick[list1, GCD[list1[[All, 1]], list1[[All,2]]], 1]` instead. `GCD[list, list]` is vectorized, while Select is not.

Comment: The array unpacking happening with the first example will take a chunk of time....

Comment: @ciao Isn't the second approach also unpacking the array? I understand the fact that Pick is a better option. But why is the first Select slower than the second Select?

Comment: @CarlWoll If you can please elaborate and add an answer. Why isn't Select considered a vectorized function?

Comment: @FixedPoint - nope, in the second example list1 is created unpacked.

BTW `Pick[list1, 
 Developer`ToPackedArray@GCD[list1[[All, 1]], list1[[All, 2]]], 1]` will cut time quite a bit using list1 from first example - to about 1/2 the time of your second example total.